# Integrate Cloudflare CDN to laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cdn, cloudflare

I want to integrate cloudflare cdn into my laravel project and I am new to laravel. Can anyone guide me in achieving this or any document or tutorial from where I can achieve this. Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is off topic for SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these easy step-by-step instructions.

Step 1: Create a Cloudflare Account and Add Your Website. First, navigate to the Cloudflare homepage and click on the Sign Up button at the top of the screen.

Step 2: Update Your Domain Name Servers and Choose a Plan.

Step 3: Review Your Cloudflare Security Settings.

For more Help view tutorial [link](https://www.a2hosting.com/blog/enable-cloudflare/)

Comment: thanks for the reply Rakesh Kumar Oad. If I follow those 3 steps, does my website is automatically link to cdn or am i do any config changes

Comment: no need to changes follow tutorial you will get your result .

Comment: okay thanks again. will try